# How to solve this Laplace boundary value problem by Fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

can someone help me?, I don't know how to proceed in the last boundary condition $u_{y}(x,1)=x(1-x)\ $

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0\ $, $\ 0<x<1,\ 0<y<1$

$u(0,y)=0$

$u(1,y)=0$

$u_{y}(x,0)=0$

$u_{y}(x,1)=x(1-x)\ $

Now, I obtain this solution for the first three conditions:

$$
A_o/2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cdot \cosh(kx) \cdot \cos(ky)
$$

k=n$\pi$

it's that correct? how I can proceed in the last boundary condition? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your general solution approach? What method are you using?

Comment: by fourier series!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separation of variables equation is
$$
        -\frac{X''}{X} = \lambda = \frac{Y''}{Y}
$$
In order to vanish in $x$ and $0$ and $1$, the separated solutions in $X$ must be
$$
                   X_n(x) = \sin(n\pi x),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
This determines $\lambda=n^2\pi^2$; because the corresponding solution $Y_n$ must satisfy $Y_n'(0)=0$, then
$$
               Y_{n}(y)=\cosh(n\pi y).
$$
The general solution is
$$
        u(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x)\cosh(n\pi y),
$$
where $A_n$ are constants determined by
$$
          u_{y}(x,1)=x(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_nn\pi\sin(n\pi x)\sinh(n\pi).
$$
Using the orthogonality of the $X_n$,
$$
            \int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)\sin(n\pi x)dx=A_n\sinh(n\pi)\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx \\
       A_n = \frac{\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)\sin(n\pi x)dx}{\sinh(n\pi)\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx}.
$$

Comment: thanks! I think I was right, and another question? it's necesary put the Ao/2 therm?

Comment: If you put a constant in front of every term in the series, and if you use the correct way of isolating the constants, $A_0/2$ is never necessary. $A_0/2$ is just a way of making all of the normalization terms to be the same constant. Here the normalization terms are already all alike because $\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)$ is the same for all $n=1,2,3,4,\cdots$.